# aws cli outputs DEBUG info without me asking for it

Tags: amazon-web-services, stdout, amazon-iam, aws-cli, stderr

If I execute `aws iam get-user`, I get:

```
DEBUG:awscli.clidriver:OrderedDict([('user-name', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7fbba4612310>)])
DEBUG:awscli.formatter:RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "myname",
        "UserId": "my id",
        "Arn": "arn/user",
        "CreateDate": "1970-01-15T12:38:27Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "1970-01-17T07:19:20Z"
    }
}
```

If I execute `aws iam get-user 2> nul`, I get:

```
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "myname",
        "UserId": "my id",
        "Arn": "arn/user",
        "CreateDate": "1970-01-15T12:38:27Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "1970-01-17T07:19:20Z"
    }
}
```

Additional information:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = my-favourite-region
```

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.59 Python/3.8.3 Linux/5.7.9-1-MANJARO botocore/1.16.9
```

```
$ which aws
/home/enanone/.local/bin/aws
```

**How can I remove the DEBUG logs from the AWS CLI output?** Can I remove them at all, or must they stay there? Thanks for any input!

Comment: `debug` is bolean flag so its only run if `--debug` is a pass to the command.  this is not the expected behaviour might be version is too old or you can try with `aws iam get-user --output json`

Comment: Hi @Adiii, thank you for the anwser! `aws iam get-user --output json` produces exactly the same output as `aws iam get-user`; that is, the `DEBUG` lines on the top are still there :(

Comment: then upgrade the aws-cli version, it seems very old https://fossies.org/linux/aws-cli/CHANGELOG.rst

Comment: `curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install`

Comment: Whereas that may be a solution, I would love to have a solution using aws cli 1. There are quite a few changes going to aws cli 2 and for the time being I'd prefer to stick to version 1. I just cannot believe I cannot get rid of those annoying `DEBUG` lines...